# Hibernate and the Repository Pattern

Tags: java, repository, hibernate, gwt

I have already asked a question on stack**overflow** on [how to understand the Reporitory Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305199/repository-pattern-how-to-understand-it-and-how-does-it-work-with-complex-en) but I'm still having very big troubles in getting a good design implemented on my server. I'm desperately trying to refactor my server and move a lot of service-code into repositories (where it actually belongs).

Here is what we are talking about:

- Hibernate ORM
- GWT 2.7.0 Server / Client (Web Application)

What can happen for example is that the client sends me a `ToolSetDTO` like this to store it in the database (the `@OneToMany` etc. annotations are there just to show you the relation between those DTOs as they reflect the relation in the database):

```
public class ToolSetDTO {
    Long id;
    @OneToOne
    public ToolDTO tool1;
    @OneToOne
    public ToolDTO tool2;
}

public class ToolDTO {
    public Long id;
    @OneToMany
    public ToolDescriptionDTO toolDescription;
}

public class ToolDescriptionDTO {
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    @OneToMany
    public String LanguageDTO;
}

public class LanguageDTO {
    public Long id;
    public String name;
}
```

as it arrives on my server, the service routine takes that DTO and tries to save it and to return the stored DTO object with valid IDs etc.

```
@Override
public ToolSetDTO persistToolSet(ToolStoreDTO toolStoreDto, ToolSetDTO toolSetDto) {
    ToolSetRepository toolSetRepository = new ToolSetRepository();  
    ToolSetDTO savedToolSetDto = toolSetRepository.save(toolStoreDto, toolSetDto);
    return savedToolSetDto;
}
```

and we arrive already at the first problem. The incoming `toolStoreDto` could contain a fake ID causing hibernate to store a `ToolSet` into the list of another `ToolStore`. So I was thinking about doing this:

```
private String getSessionId() {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = getThreadLocalRequest();
    return httpRequest.getSession().getId();
}

@Override
public ToolSetDTO persistToolSet(ToolStoreDTO toolStoreDto, ToolSetDTO toolSetDto) {
    ToolSetRepository toolSetRepository = new ToolSetRepository(this.getSessionId());   
    ToolSetDTO savedToolSetDto = toolSetRepository.save(toolStoreDto, toolSetDto);
    return savedToolSetDto;
}
```

Just pass the session ID to `ToolSetRepository` that accesses the `ToolStore` as follows via the `ToolStoreRepository` that internally checks if the access is allowed or not. **I am not sure if I designed that well..**

```
public abstract class AbstractXsrfRepository<T> extends AbstractRepository<T> {

    private String sessionId;
    public AbstractXsrfRepository(String sessionId) {
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
    }
    protected String getSessionId() {
        return this.sessionId;
    }
}

public class ToolStoreRepository extends AbstractXsrfRepository<ToolStoreDTO> {
    @Override
    public ToolStoreDTO get(Long id) {
        this.openSession();
        ToolStoreOwnerRepository toolStoreOwnerRepo = new ToolStoreOwnerRepository(this.getSessionId());
        ToolStoreOwnerDTO toolStoreOwnerDto = toolStoreOwnerRepo.get(null);
        Long toolStoreOwnerId = toolStoreOwnerDto.getId();

        Criteria cr = this.getSession().createCriteria(ToolStore.class);
        cr.add(Restrictions.eq("toolStoreOwner.id", toolStoreOwnerId));
        cr.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<ToolStore> toolStores = cr.list();

        if(toolStores.isEmpty() == true) {
            String err = "toolStoreOwner.id seems not to be associated with toolStore.id";
            throw new RuntimeException(err);
        }

        ToolStoreDTO toolStoreDto = ConvertEntity.converToolStore(toolStores.get(0));
        this.closeSession();
        return toolStoreDto;
    }
}
```

**Beforehand:** The fact that `get(Long id)` returns just a DTO and not the Entity object is a problem for me. I sometimes need access to `ToolStore` from other repositories but they can't retrieve them from `ToolStoreRepository`. They would have to re-implement `private getToolStore(Long id)` that does the exact same as `ToolStoreRepository.get(Long id)`.

Saving a `ToolSet` could then look something like this:

```
public class ToolSetRepository<ToolSetDTO> {

    public ToolSetDTO save(ToolStoreDTO toolStoreDto, ToolSetDTO toolSetDto) {
        this.openSessionWithTransaction();
        ToolStoreRepository toolStoreRepository = new ToolStoreRepository();
        ToolStore toolStore = toolStoreRepository.get(toolStoreDto.getId());

        // ..

        Tool tool1 = null;
        ToolDTO tool1Dto = toolSetDto.getTool1();

        if(tool1Dto != null) {
            ToolDTO toolDto = tool1Dto.getTool();
            ToolDescriptionDTO toolDescriptionDto = toolDto.getToolDescription(languageDto.getId());
            // PLEASE NOTE: That toolDescriptionRepository.save() returns an Entity and not a DTO!
            ToolDescription toolDescription = toolDescriptionRepository.save(toolStoreDto, languageDto, toolDto, toolDescriptionDto);

            ToolRepository toolRepository = new MiddayMenuAppetizerRepository();
            tool1 = toolRepository.merge(toolStoreDto, toolDescription.getTool());
        }

        // ..

        ToolSet toolSet = new ToolSet(toolStore, tool1, tool2);     
        ToolSetDTO savedToolSetDto = ConvertEntity.convertToolSet(toolSet);     
        this.closeSessionWithTransaction();

        return savedToolSetDto;
    }
}
```

As you can see in one comment `// PLEASE NOTE ..` The `ToolDescriptionRepository.save()` does return an Entity object! That is another problem I am confronted with my design at the moment. As I understood it, The repository should *only* take business objects and return business objects. Here I am violating this constraint!

**And that is where I am now:** Assuming that my `abstract class AbstractXsrfRepository<T>` wasn't such a bad idea, I was thinking about another abstract class `AbstractToolStoreRepository`. But why? because I could do this:

```
public class AbstractToolStoreRepository extends AbstractXsrfRepository<ToolSetDTO> {

    public AbstractToolStoreRepository(String sessionId) {
        super(sessionId);
    }

    protected ToolStore get(Long id) {
        // Implementation of ToolSetRepository.get(Long id);
        // that checks with "this.getSessionId()" if the access is 
        // valid or not.
    }
}
```

and let every repository class that has somehow to get access to `ToolStore` implement `AbstractToolStoreRepository`. *Please note that `get(Long id)` is now `protected` and returns `ToolStore` instead of `ToolStoreDTO`!* That way such a repository could access `ToolStore` without having to re-implement the `get(Long id)` function from above and I don't have to make a function that actually returns an Entity object `public` - instead it's just `protected` and provided by `AbstractToolStoreRepository`.

What could also be done is e.g. just throwing away the `AbstractXsrfRepository<T>` abstract class and move those few lines right directly into `AbstractToolStoreRepository` because one could argue that `AbstractXsrfRepository<T>` in fact doesn't really do anything. The actual work is done by the the implementing class of `AbstractXsrfRepository` which is here `AbstractToolStoreRepository`.

I am not sure if anybody is going to read all that but if somebody got the time I'd like to know if this whole `AbstractXsrfRepository<T>` thing was a good idea and if I should extend this inheritance chain to `AbstractToolStoreRepository` or if I'll come into hells kitchen or something..

Comment: You have defined twice ``ToolDTO``. Also why are you saving a DTO?

Comment: @gonzalon Some copy paste errors. The DTO just contains the data I am saving.